# Unix--> Concatenate file name + variable content and search it

Tags: shell, unix

I am new with shell scripting...I am trying to remove a file which is named with the previous PID, but I don't know hot to concatenate The old PId to the file name :(
This is my code

...

```
cp ./template_dos ./user_dos.new
diff ./user_dos.new ./user_dos
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
  if [[ -f user_dos.PID ]] ; then  #Here I search for the OLD PID->2145
  rm user_dos.PID #I would like to remove the user_dos.2145 (value old PID) I fail as i searchs for the word PID...and I want the content!
  fi
  mv user_dos  user_dos.$$ 
  mv user_dos.new user_dos
  echo $$ > PID
fi
```

Comment: I know, if the PID variable would be an envy I could do something like user_dos.${PID}, but I got no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `PID` from the file:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
  if [[ -f user_dos\.$(cat PID 2>/dev/null) ]] ; then  
  rm user_dos\.$(cat PID 2>/dev/null)
  mv user_dos  user_dos.$$ 
  mv user_dos.new user_dos
  echo $$ > PID
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I did and worked

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
  if [[ -f PID ]] ; then
    MYPID=`cat PID`
  fi
  if [[ -f user_dos.$MYPID ]] ; then
    rm user_dos.$MYPID
  fi
  mv user_dos  user_dos.$$
  mv user_dos.new user_dos
  echo $$ > PID
fi
```